# how do i take the rain away from 2 sloping roofs meeting in the middle?

Tags: roof, waterproofing

i have an extension on the side of the house with a pitched roof with a gutter and downpipe to take the rain away. There is a carport to the front of this extension at the front of the house with the roof sloping back and sharing this gutter. I want to convert the carport into a room and open up the existing extension. Whats the best way to make rainproof the two meeting pitched roofs please

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! I'm a bit confused by your question, as it seems to be touching on a few different things. Do you want to know how to waterproof the intersection of 2 sloped roofs? Or how to install a downspout? Or how to divert the water to a different downspout?

Comment: A diagram or picture would also help.

Comment: What you described would appear like this: https://gyazo.com/96523cf7e118c8fe1dbc483982fe07d1

Answer (score 1):

Use metal flashing to create a waterproof channel where the roofs join, making sure it is tilted enough to drain to the gutters at the edges. Apply roofing so it overlaps and directs water into that channel.